# php post: replace single quote with double single for sqlserver query

Tags: php, sql-server, yii2

my `$POST` value is "WYNN'S". When I create an sql query via Yii2 framework:

```
$vendor = (new Query()) ->select('VendorNo') ->distinct() ->from('Pm_Item i') ->innerJoin('[PurchPrice] [p]', 'p.ItemNo = i.ItemNo AND p.CompanyKey = i.CompanyKey') ->where($condition)->all();
```

i get an error:

`Incorrect syntax near 'S'.
The SQL being executed was: SELECT DISTINCT [TopCode] FROM [PM_Item] WHERE  Brand IN( 'WYNN'S')`

How can I replace 'WYNN'S' with 'WYNN''S' using php?

UPDATE:

```
    $condition = '';
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($filters as $filter) {
        if (isset($filter['selected'])) {
            if (strpos( $filter['selected']['value'], "'") !== false) {
                $filter['selected']['value'] =  str_replace("'", "''", $filter['selected']['value']); //preg_replace('/\'/', '\'\'', $filter['selected']['value']);
            }
            if ($i != 0 AND $filter['selected']['value'] != '') {
                $condition .= ' AND i.' . $filter['column'] . ' = \'' . $filter['selected']['value'] . '\'';
            } elseif ($filter['selected']['value'] != '') {
                $condition .= 'i.' . $filter['column'] . ' = \'' . $filter['selected']['value'] . '\'';
            }

            $i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you create this sql query?

Comment: I use Yii2 framework: `                $vendor = (new Query())
                    ->select('VendorNo')
                    ->distinct()
                    ->from('Pm_Item i')
                    ->innerJoin('[PurchPrice] [p]', 'p.ItemNo = i.ItemNo AND p.CompanyKey = i.CompanyKey')
                    ->where($condition)->all();`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/130323/7926064

Comment: @BNT, how do I properly escape single quotes in mssql?

Comment: @Lyuba please provide full code sample, especially how you construct `$condition`

Answer (score 1):

uses addslashes() to add backslash befor special character of string

```
$str = addslashes("WYNN'S");
```

then pass to sql query.

Answer (score 0):

the str_replace() function seems to do that:

```
<?php
  $query = str_replace("'", "''" , $query);
?>
```

That would replace every occurance of a ' with 2 of them: ''.

Comment: please note, that while this might work, its always best to thoroughly escape userinput as described at e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/130323/7926064)

Comment: This does not work, I already wrap WYNN'S into single quotes when I create $condition for sql query, and replacement of single with double does not affect the string

Answer (score 0):

you should escape the special characters in your sql statements

if you are using the **mysqli** extention , use the **mysqli::real_escape_string** to scapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement (including the single quote)

```
// Query
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='%s' AND password='%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($user),
            mysql_real_escape_string($password));
```

as for the **PDO** extention , use **PDO::quote** or  **PDO Prepare**

and if you are using the deprecated mysql extension , you can use  **mysql-real-escape-string**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

example:

```
$lastname  = "O'Reilly";
$_lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($lastname);
$query = "SELECT * FROM actors WHERE last_name = '$_lastname'";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to write a escape function and use that for every value in the query:

```
function escape_sql(string $string) 
{
   return str_replace("'", "''", $string);
}

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT [TopCode] 
          FROM [PM_Item] 
          WHERE  Brand IN( '". escape_sql("WYNN'S"). "')";
?>
```

Or go for a PDO approach where you could let PHP figure it out using `->prepare()` and `->bindValue()`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed only too late you are using yii.

Would the part ->where() not have to be like:

->where(['in', 'Brand', ["WYNN'S"]])

according to http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#where()-detail this would lead to propper escaping by yii